# При перезагрузке пропадает pppoe-соединение Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, pppoe

Подключил интернет в свою деревню, но роутера для автоматического установления pppoe нет. На линуксе установил pppoe соединение через pppoeconf, после появляется соединение с интернетом ровно до перезагрузки. Перезагрузив, pppoe не подключается. Я захожу через "sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces" и удаляю "auto enp3s0 iface enp3s0 inet manual"(скриншот ниже). Потом снова запускаю pppoeconf, ввожу все данные, и до перезагрузки у меня есть стабильный интернет. Я не спец в линуксе вовсе и даже не представялю, что вам предоставить для решения проблемы. Заранее спасибо.

P.S На винде запускаю вручную, нажимая на шарик внизу и выбирая pppoe соединение, которое создал ранее, и интернет появляется(если вы знаете решение и для винды - я вас обниму). [image: введите сюда описание изображения]